# How to upload pytorch model to AWS S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I have a pytorch model. I want to access this model from cloud. I need to get a url like in the example below. What steps do I need to follow? can I do drag and drop like google drive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set up VPC, Upload to S3 bucket and use a bucket VPC endpoint to access the model on the fly wherever you are.